# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df_11=

    dataReceived time_diff3 time
0           1   76.356133   15:00:56.052554
1           1   68.195077   15:02:18.764644
2           1   141.308039  15:03:38.039307
3           1   48.674365   15:06:22.955319
4           1   113.261287  15:07:57.382506
... ... ... ... ... ...
6050        1   18.000000   02:43:10
6051        1   18.000000   02:43:28
6052        1   19.000000   02:43:46
6053        1   18.000000   02:44:05
6054        1   0.000000    02:44:23
```

I want to plot :

```
ax1 = df_11.plot(kind='scatter', x='time', y='time_diff3', color='r')    

print(ax1)
```

And I got the following error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'
```

I dont understand why I cant plot this graph, since column `time` is `datetime.time`. How am I supposed to convert datetime.time to datetime64?

Answer (score 1):

You could coerce "time" column to datetime using `to_datetime` and extract the time component using `dt.strftime`. You may want to rotate the labels:

```
df_11['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_11['time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M%S')
ax1 = df_11.plot(kind='scatter', x='time', y='time_diff3', color='r')
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(df['time'])
ax1.set_xticklabels(df['time'], rotation=45);
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer, when I try using "to_datetime" I got the following error: `TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`. Moreover some elements in the time column contain milliseconds and others do not

Comment: @QQ1821 try `df_11['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_11['time'].astype(str)).dt.strftime('%H:%M%S')` in the first line.

Comment: why not simply use `df['time'].astype(str)`, given the input is a series of dtype datetime.time ?

Comment: @FObersteiner you're right. Now that you mention it, converting to datetime is indeed redundant.